# How to parse until a token is found on a line by itself

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to parse the following document:

```
val doc = """BEGIN
A Bunch
Of Text
With linebreaks
##
"""
```

The idea here being that when I see a `##` on a line of its own, I should consider that the end of parsing.

I've tried, using the following code to parse this document:

```
object MyParser extends RegexParsers {
    val begin: Parser[String] = "BEGIN"
    val lines: Parser[Seq[String]] = repsep(line, eol)
    val line: Parser[String] = """.+""".r
    val eol: Parser[Any] = "\n" | "\r\n" | "\r"
    val end: Parser[String] = "##"

    val document: Parser[Seq[String]] = 
      begin ~> lines <~ end 

}

MyParser.parseAll(MyParser.document, doc)
```

However when I try to execute this (in an Annonite script), I get the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$class.rep1sep(Parsers.scala:771)
  ammonite.$file.vtt$minusparser$MyParser$.rep1sep(vtt-parser.sc:3)
  scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$class.repsep(Parsers.scala:687)
  ammonite.$file.vtt$minusparser$MyParser$.repsep(vtt-parser.sc:3)
  ammonite.$file.vtt$minusparser$MyParser$.<init>(vtt-parser.sc:5)
  ammonite.$file.vtt$minusparser$MyParser$.<clinit>(vtt-parser.sc)
  ammonite.$file.vtt$minusparser$.<init>(vtt-parser.sc:22)
  ammonite.$file.vtt$minusparser$.<clinit>(vtt-parser.sc)
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `line` and `eol` are defined as normal class field `val`s, but they are used in `lines` before their definition. The code that assigns values to class fields is executed sequentially in the constructor, and `line` and `eol` are both still `null`, when `lines` is being assigned.

To solve this define `line` and `eol` as `lazy val`s or `def`s, or just put them before `lines` in the code.

---

The parser itself also has some problems. By default Scala parsers automatically ignore all whitespace, including EOLs. Considering that regexp `.*` without any flags does *not* include EOLs, `line` naturally means "the whole line until the line break", so you don't have to analyze EOLs at all.

Secondly, the `lines` parser as defined is greedy. It will happily consume everything including the final `##`. To make it stop before `end` you can, for example, use the `not` combinator.

With all the changes, the parser looks like this:

```
object MyParser extends RegexParsers {
  val begin: Parser[String] = "BEGIN"
  val line: Parser[String] = """.+""".r
  val lines: Parser[Seq[String]] =  rep(not(end) ~> line)
  val end: Parser[String] = "##"

  val document: Parser[Seq[String]] =
    begin ~> lines <~ end
}
```

You may also override the behaviour of skipping the whitespace, and analyze all whitespace manually. This includes the whitespace after `BEGIN` and after the `##`:

```
object MyParser extends RegexParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false

  val eol: Parser[Any] = "\n" | "\r\n" | "\r"
  val begin: Parser[String] = "BEGIN" <~ eol
  val line: Parser[String] = """.*""".r
  val lines: Parser[Seq[String]] =  rep(not(end) ~> line <~ eol)
  val end: Parser[String] = "##"

  val document: Parser[Seq[String]] =
    begin ~> lines <~ end <~ whiteSpace

}
```

Note, that `line` is defined as `.*` instead of `.+` here. Like this the parser won't fail if there're any empty lines in the input.

Comment: Beautiful thank you so much for taking the time to give a thorough explanation and expand on a better solution